# Search page returned total count != actual visible returned count for the requesting user

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

## EDITED

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A109749+%5Bc%23%5D

returns 102 Qs and As

My user page indicates 89, but the onhover adds to 87.

[image: le old screenshot]

So I have 12 deleted posts on SO for C# (eh, wow), and the search returns the count of all of those, but I can't see all of them. (not 10k yet) Adding the "wiki:0" qualifier (as one example) changes that to be "accurate".

---

Addendum:

@TimStone points out this demonstrates the problem nicely:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A150235+%5Bmarkdown%5D

vs

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A150235+%5Bmarkdown%5D+wiki%3A0

Comment: also of note, this page is really slow to update (the search page) since I answered another and am up to 80/8/2/12 and 102, not 79/8/2/12 and 101.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fetch for tag/user combinations is treated in a special way, one that did not correctly account for deleted vs not in the initial search for post IDs that were results.  Note: adding `wiki:0` took it on a different code path.

This had 2 effects discussed in comments here:

1. Total counts were off
2. Page counts were off

Page counts were off because we *re*-check for deleted or not when performing the per-page query (since content may have been deleted since we last indexed), since deleted posts were in that paged list of IDs, you saw sub-full counts there.

The cause of both of these will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: In summary: we *aren't* going crazy. (At least not because of this...)

Answer (score 3):

[Try this instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A109749+[c%23]+wiki%3A0)

The tag counts and scores are for **non-wiki** questions and answers.

I manually counted 89 posts, so the number that appears on the profile page seems correct (albeit a tad confusing).

I can only assume the count of 100 must include deleted posts.

Comment: I don't have 10k on SO, so I can't check if any answers were deleted recently.

Comment: The 89 is (correctly) the sum of all his questions and answers, regardless of wiki status. I think the 100 might be inclusive of deleted content, but I'm not sure.

Comment: cool, now what about the 100 vs 89? surely I don't have 11 deleted answers/Qs out there, but I can't see those so idk.

Comment: If 89 is the actual count of everything not deleted, then come to think of it, the number on the profile page is probably correct (albeit a bit confusing), and this is a bug with search.

Comment: WTF. This may be separate, but I think there's a bug in the paging algorithm -- on 50 posts/page setting, I *twice* manually counted 49 on the first page, 40 on the second page. So 89 looks correct, regardless of how they appear.

Comment: I imagine I've mis classified the bug. I would love someone to reclassify it appropriately. I know I found an issue, but I'm not sure _what_ the issue is, persay.

Comment: @JonSeigel Oh good, I'm not crazy then. I saw the same thing, but inconsistently, so I thought maybe I miscounted.

Comment: @dra: It would appear there are *two* issues here...

Comment: @Jon ~ Most likely. I would like the tooltip to list all (wiki and non-wiki) but I want the search/paging to be corrected too.

Comment: @Jon: I also count 49+40(+1). However, my guess is that this is not a pagination issue, but rather that for whatever reason there's 1 item not shown on the first page, and 10 items not shown on the second.